# Can the Fibonacci sum $\sum_{i=0}^N x^i F_{a+ib}$, for integers $x$, $a$, $b$, be determined by a direct formula or generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Suppose we have a variable $x$ such that $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Let

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^N  F_{a+i.b}. x^i$$

where $F_i$ is the $i$-th Fibonacci number, $a$ and $b$ are constants having range between $0\leq a,b\leq10^{9}$, and $N$ can be a big value up to $10^{18}$

Here's an example let's suppose $a=0,b=2,x=1,N=4$ then $$S=F_0+F_2+F_4+F_6+F_8=33$$

> Can $S$ be solved using a direct formula or maybe a generating function? If yes, how?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: It's a homework question given by my teacher

Comment: a+ib is so confusing here

Comment: With questions like this, generally the place to look is what occurred just before this.  For example, did you have the formula for the infinite series $\sum_k F_k x^k$ ?  Can you use the same method to get the infinite series $\sum_k F_{a+kb} x^k$? Then subtract two of these to get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-th Fibonacci number is
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(\phi^n-\psi^n),$$
where $\phi=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt5)$ and $\psi=\frac12(1-\sqrt5)$. Thus
$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{k=0}^NF_{a+bk}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(\phi^{a+bk}-\psi^{a+bk})x^k\\
&=\frac{\phi^a}{\sqrt5}\sum_{k=0}^N(\phi^bx)^k-\frac{\psi^a}{\sqrt5}\sum_{k=0}^N(\psi^bx)^k\\
&=\frac{\phi^a}{\sqrt5}\cdot\frac{(\phi^bx)^N-1}{\phi^bx-1}-\frac{\psi^a}{\sqrt5}\cdot\frac{(\psi^bx)^N-1}{\psi^bx-1}.
\end{align}$$
This is of course making the assumption that $x\ne \phi^{-b},\psi^{-b}$.